# sum values based in agent ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have a sheet with agent id's in column a and under each ID is a sub identifier with a value in column b of 1 - 7 
sub identifiers are 
Break_1000
Meeting_2000
Training_3000
Personal_4000
System_Outage_5000
Activations_6000
Outbound_7000
Using the sub values, any agent ID may have anywhere from 1 to 7 of the above identifiers. and I would like a way to sum each Agent ID (a:a) by sub identifier

The results I expect would be 
E13 Agent ID_1008, F13 meeting_2000, G13 outbound_7000 F14 2, G14 7, 
Row 13 would have columns containing the ID's 
and
Row 14 would contain the values associated with those ID's
make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet since I believe the question needs a bit of clarification.

If there are multiple sub_ids are they all in the same row?  or is there multiple rows for an agent_id.

If you just want the number of agents with a given sub_id you could use countif.

```
=countif(B:B,sub_id)
```

If they are all in the same column you could just find what row they are in using something like:

```
=row(index(A:A),match(AGENT_ID,A:A,0)))
```

This would give the rows for each one and then you would need to find the row that is 1 higher and subtract your row from this  Assuming you have a list of agents in column D and a their row calc in column E.

```
=small(E:E,RANK(E2,E:E,1)+1)-E2-1
```

Note this won't work for the last agent since there is nothing to subtract from.

Otherwise I would suggest setting up the table in a more usable format, storing multiple types of data in one column is generally poor data structure and generally makes it tough to work with.

Gordon

Comment: I think you still have an issue with what your calling row vs column.  You say their all in the same row but the comment has everything in column A with everything in different rows.

Comment: Sorry about that you are correct they are all int he same column. the values are in column B which could be anything as long as each Sub ID and sub id value, is matched to each agent ID